# Pentaho more authentication providers

Tags: authentication, pentaho, provider

I need to develop two custom authentication providers able to handle 2 main use case:

- login via username and password form authentication
- authentication via token

I ve developed my CustomFormAuthProvider and CustomTokenAuthProvider.

Inside Pentaho appContext-spring-security.xml i  have declared both providers beans with

```
providername=custom
```

and consequently i have set the corresponding property (in security.properties) to "custom".

When i startup pentaho i can see that AccessManager object loads just one provider of the two... So it catches an error when i use one of the two authentication method.

Is there a way to load both providers in the provider list, the way that the access manager can load the correct one which supports the current token type?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this could be the answer
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0P0/150/010/080

Editing the

```
applicationcontext-spring-security.xml
```

it is possible to add more providers in the ProviderManager providers list like the code below

```
 <bean id="authenticationManager"class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
<property name="providers">
    <list>
        <pen:bean class="org.springframework.security.providers.AuthenticationProvider">
                <pen:attributes>
                    <pen:attr key="providerName" value="jackrabbit"/> 
                </pen:attributes></pen:bean>
        <pen:bean class="org.springframework.security.providers.AuthenticationProvider">     
                 <pen:attributes> 
                    <pen:attr key="providerName" value="webservice"/>
                  </pen:attributes>
        </pen:bean>
        <ref local="anonymousAuthenticationProvider" />
    </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

i will try it